# CORS error in Angularjs app in chrome accessing .NET Web Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors, ngresource

I've read a vast number of existing questions on CORS and angular - and how it's not an issue for angular but needs to be setup on the server. I've tried so many suggestions but can't get it working.

I have an angularJS app that sits within my ASP MVc page.
It gets its data (formatted as JSON) from a web api 2 app in which I have enabled CORS.

The controller is :

```
    [EnableCors("http://localhost:3419", "*", "*")]
    public class DashboardsController : ApiController
    {
        private IDashboardService _dashboardService;

        public DashboardsController(IDashboardService dashboardService)
        {
            this._dashboardService = dashboardService;

        }


      [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery()]
    [Route("api/dashboards/")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var dashboards = _dashboardService.GetAllDashboards().AsQueryable();

             return Ok(dashboards);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added

```
config.EnableCors();
```

to  webapiconfig.

So theoretically this should now allow cors?
It works fine in ie, but in chrome no.

So additionally found reference to the OPTIONS handler in web.config so commented that out thus:

```
> <system.webServer>
>     <handlers>
>       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
>       <!--<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />-->
>       <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
>       <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
> preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
>     </handlers>   </system.webServer>
```

still no joy. So more digging led to adding the following in global.asax :

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

Everything I've found about server side I've tried and doesn't work, so I'm assuming it's something client side.

The angular app uses $resource to access the api and get the data:

```
    function getAllDashboards() {
        var dashboards = $resource(appSettings.serverPath + 'api/dashboards/:id', { id: '@id' }).query();
        return dashboards;
    }
```

I'm quite new to angular, but understood $resource to be a wrapper for $httpProvider. Then only things I can find for angular and CORS issues were to add the following:

```
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
                delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

I've done this, still doesn't work, but then I'm not actually using $httpProvider, but $resource.

Is there something I need to do with angular and $resource to get this working?
As I say, in IE11 it works fine and watching in fiddler the data is getting retrieved in chrome but just comes back with error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2773//api/dashboards. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3419' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

UPDATE:
Following the suggestion from vidalsasoon it now works when running in chrome via Visual Studio (2012) but still not when on the server (Windows 2008 R2 & IIS7.5), even though still working in IE

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the worry about the OPTIONS part until you do a POST. That's step 2. First just try doing a GET.

Another test would be trying to add these lines to your server web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's worked locally running both via Visual Studio, but still not working on the server on iis. Still working fine in IE, but via chrome getting 401 not authorised when accessing the api. Fiddler shows it to be:  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>